# Search by sum of multiple columns in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table of data about properties that includes the bathrooms broken down by 1/4 baths, 1/2 bath, 3/4 bath & full bath, but I want people to be able to search by total baths (the sum of the 4 types of baths).  I have come up with this query which works but seems inelegant.  Is there a cleaner/better way to do this?  Specifically I tried to use TotalBaths in the where clause but it did not work.  I am using coalesce because sometimes the values are NULL.  This is an example if the person search for 2 or 3 bathrooms.

```
SELECT *, 
         COALESCE(FullBathrooms,0)+ 
         COALESCE(HalfBathrooms,0)+ 
         COALESCE(OneQuarterBaths,0)+
         COALESCE(ThreeQuarterBaths,0) as TotalBaths 

FROM properties 
WHERE ( COALESCE(FullBathrooms,0)+
        COALESCE(HalfBathrooms,0)+
        COALESCE(OneQuarterBaths,0)+
        COALESCE(ThreeQuarterBaths,0) BETWEEN 2 AND 3 
       ) 
ORDER BY Price DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: You can limit your queries on the results of aggregates by a `HAVING` clause (though it does have some overhead, as the totals have be calculated).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use the `having` expression instead of `where`.  The `having` clause lets you use column aliases:

```
SELECT *,
       (COALESCE(FullBathrooms,0) + COALESCE(HalfBathrooms,0) + 
        COALESCE(OneQuarterBaths,0)+ COALESCE(ThreeQuarterBaths,0)
       ) as TotalBaths
FROM properties
HAVING TotalBaths between 2 and 3
ORDER BY Price DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

You can also do it with a subquery -- but this might not perform as well because the subquery might be materialized:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             (COALESCE(FullBathrooms,0) + COALESCE(HalfBathrooms,0) + 
              COALESCE(OneQuarterBaths,0)+ COALESCE(ThreeQuarterBaths,0)
             ) as TotalBaths
      from properties p
     ) p
where TotalBaths between 2 and 3
ORDER BY Price DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

This is the way you would simplify this query in most other SQL engines (well, either a subquery or a CTE).

Comment: Thank you Gordon! I was unfamiliar with the having expression good one to know!